# Prove that series $(10n+4)^2+1$ contains infinitly many composite numbers

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Given sequence is 
$$4^2+1,\ 14^2+1,\ 24^2+1,\ 34^2+1...$$
How to show that there are infinite amount of composite numbers?

Comment: No non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ may attain only prime values from some point on. It is a consequence of $(a-b)\mid P(a)-P(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

dI can provide a list of numbers that follow such a form, but are composite and infinite. However, they are not exhaustive.

$$(10n+4)^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p$$
$$100n^2 + 80 n + 16 \equiv -1 \mod p$$
$$20n(5n+4) \equiv -17 \mod p$$

Here, we can simply assume that $p = 17$ to find a list of numbers of such a form that are divisible by $17$

$$20n(5n+4) \equiv 0 \mod 17$$

Therefore
$$20n \equiv 0 \mod 17$$
Or
$$5n \equiv13 \mod 17$$

Therefore, $n =0 + 17k$ or $n = 6 + 17k$

However, $n = 0$ gives $17$ ,which is prime, so we can rewrite this as

If $n = 17 + 17k$ or $6+17k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k \ge 0$, then $f(n) = (10n+4)^2 + 1$ is divisible by $17$, which gives us an infinite amount of composite numbers

Comment: I guess this can be summarized as $$17\mid n\quad\Longrightarrow 17\mid(10n+4)^2+1,$$ so there are infinite composite numbers in the given sequence.

Comment: That's true, I just also wanted to point out that $n \equiv 6 \mod 17$ could also be found using this method.

Comment: But some $n$s such that $n=6\pmod{17}$ are not composite... A way out is to ask that $n=6+34k$.

Comment: The $n$ is plugged into the equation $10n+4)^2 + 1$, which gives us a composite value. clearly $23$ is prime, but $(10 \cdot 23 +4)^2 + 1$ is divisible by 17

Answer (score 0):

If you take any prime $p$ such that $p\mid (10n+4)^2+1$ then $p\mid (10(n+kp)+4)^2+1$ because $$(10(n+kp)+4)^2+1=(10n+4+kp)^2+1=(10n+4)^2+2kp(10n+4)+k^2p^2+1=(10n+4)^2+1+p(2k(10n+4)+k^2p)$$
And trivially $$p\mid p(2k(10n+4)+k^2p)$$